# How the pass the output of one sparql query as a input to another sparql query

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying get the dbpedia movie link using the movie name in the first query and pass that link in the second query to get the movies similar to this movie.For e.g Lagaan.Now instead of passing the link manually in the second query is there a way to combine the two queries and pass the output of first query as an input to the second query.i.e:the link of the movie lagaan.Also,if the first query gives multiple links eg:if i am searching for Harry potter it will return multiple harry potter series links so,it should handle that case as well.

### Query1

```sql
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
        prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

          select distinct ?film where  {
          ?film a dbpedia-owl:Film .
          ?film rdfs:label ?label .
          filter regex( str(?label), "Lagaan", "i")
          }
          limit 10
```

### Query 2

```sql
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
        select ?similar (count(?p) as ?similarity) where { 
          values ?movie { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lagaan> }
          ?similar ?p ?o ; a dbpedia-owl:Film .
          ?movie   ?p ?o .
        }
        group by ?similar ?movie
        having count(?p) > 35
        order by desc(?similarity)
```

Edited query:

```sql
  select ?film ?similar (count(?p) as ?similarity) where {

  { 
          select distinct ?film where  {
          ?film a dbpedia-owl:Film .
          ?film rdfs:label ?label .
          filter regex( str(?label), "Lagaan", "i")
          } 
  }

         ?similar ?p ?o ; a dbpedia-owl:Film .
         ?film  ?p ?o .
        }
        group by ?similar ?film
        having count(?p) > 35
        order by desc(?similarity)
```

corrected query as told by Joshua Taylor

```sql
select ?film ?other (count(*) as ?similarity) {
  {
    select ?film where {
      ?film a dbpedia-owl:Film ; rdfs:label ?label .
      filter contains(lcase(?label),"lagaan")
    }
    limit 1
  }
  ?film ?p ?o .
  ?other a dbpedia-owl:Film ; ?p ?o .
}
group by ?film ?other
having count(?p) > 25
order by desc(?similarity)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way to combine the two queries and pass the output of first
>   query as an input to the second query.

SPARQL 1.1 defines subqueries.  The results of inner queries are available to outer queries, so they are "passed" to them.  In your case, you would have something along the lines of:

```sql
select ?similarMovie (... as ?similarity) where {

  { #-- QUERY 1, find one or more films
    select distinct ?film where {
      #-- ...
    }
  }

  #-- QUERY 2, find films similar to ?film
  #-- ...
}
```

Comment: ,I edited the query above,I am getting null when i tried in dbpedia endpoint.

Comment: It looks like you might find [my earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21290432/1281433) to [How to find similar content using SPARQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21290186/1281433) useful.

Comment: That said, I don't know that I see any real reason to use a subquery here;  it looks like you could just combine this into one query.

Comment: In fact;  now that I look at it, it appears that you're already using the code from that answer.  You should generally provide attribution if you're using content from other places;  the license for Stack Overflow requires attribution.

Comment: Sorry sir,I am using  stackoverflow for first tym so didnt knew about mentionind that.I wil keep this is mind from next time.Thanks u soo mch sir for all ur help.