# Finding proximity between two entity using Category matching

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, ontology, dbpedia

**All queries are tested on sparql virtuso endpoint**
I want to find the categories of two dbpedia subject like here *Bharatiya_Janata_Party and New_Delhi.* 
**I want to match how the categories of these are similar to each other.**

As here in the first query i got the categories of Bharatiya_Janata_Party.

In the Second query i got the categories of New_Delhi.

Now I want to match the result of category of Bharatiya_Janata_Party to that of New_Delhi. Like here

1. Nationalist_parties---New_Delhi
2. Nationalist_parties---New_Delhi_district
3. Nationalist_parties---Populated_places_established_in_1911
4. Nationalist_parties---Capitals_in_Asia
5. Nationalist_parties---Capitals_in_Asia
6. Nationalist_parties--Planned_capitals
7. Political_parties_established_in_1980---New_Delhi
8. Political_parties_established_in_1980---New_Delhi_district
9. .....
10. ....
    ..
    ..

I have fired a query III for making match between *Nationalist_parties---New_Delhi*. I got a match at level 4((^skos:broader){0,4}).

Similarly Again I have to do for Nationalist_parties---New_Delhi_district.

**The real problem is that i want to combine these 3 queries so that i may get the direct result in a tabular form. Is there any way to automate the whole process.**

Query I:

```
 SELECT *
    WHERE {
      dbpedia:Bharatiya_Janata_Party dcterms:subject ?x
    }
```

Result of Query I:

```
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Nationalist_parties
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Political_parties_established_in_1980
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Conservative_parties_in_India
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Hindu_political_parties
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Hindutva
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Bharatiya_Janata_Party
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:1980_establishments_in_India
```

Query II:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  dbpedia:New_Delhi dcterms:subject ?x
}
```

Result of Query II:

```
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:New_Delhi
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:New_Delhi_district
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Populated_places_established_in_1911
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Capitals_in_Asia
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Indian_capital_cities
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Planned_capitals
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Urdu-speaking_countries_and_territories
```

QUERY III:

```
select distinct ?super where {
  ?super (^skos:broader){0,4} category:Nationalist_parties, category:New_Delhi
}
```

Result:

```
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Government-related_organizations
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Government
```

**First Match at level 4 with 2 Super Classes**

P.S: It is not necessary that the other query will match at (^skos:broader){0,4}. So i am manually firing the above query from (^skos:broader){0,0} and incrementing as (^skos:broader){0,1}->(^skos:broader){0,2)...to the first match.

```
select distinct ?super where {
  ?super (^skos:broader){0,6} category:Nationalist_parties, category:New_Delhi_district
}
```

Result:

```
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Categories_by_topic
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Government
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Categories_by_parameter
dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Political_geography
```

**First Match at level 6 with 4 Super Classes**

===================================

Combining these 3 queries i want this type of result in a tabular form:-

==================================

**CategoryI(QueryI---Category(QuesryII)---Level  --count matches*

1. Nationalist_parties---New_Delhi---------------------------- 4------ 2
2. Nationalist_parties---New_Delhi_district-------------------6--------4
3. Nationalist_parties---Populated_places_established_in_1911
4. Nationalist_parties---Capitals_in_Asia
5. Nationalist_parties---Capitals_in_Asia
   ...
6. .....
7. ....

Please help me to automate and combine the above query. I have read several posts but not able to figure it how.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How the pass the output of one sparql query as a input to another sparql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282463/how-the-pass-the-output-of-one-sparql-query-as-a-input-to-another-sparql-query)

Comment: No the question is about iterating the whole process..and automating them..Please have a view if you have the solution